# Undesired result displaying ggplot boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting this data:

```
Day,Property,Violent
Mon,7.2,5.7
Tue,5,4.5
Wed,6.3,3.6
Thu,5.4,4
Fri,9.5,5.6
Sat,16,10.9
Sun,14.2,8.6
```

with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
week <- read.csv("week.csv", header=TRUE)
data.melt <- melt(week,id="Day")

ggplot() +
geom_boxplot(aes(x=Day, y= value, fill= variable), 
             data= data.melt, position = position_dodge(width = .9))
```

1. Why do my markers appear on the legend but not on the plot?
2. How can I  logically re-order the days of week beginning from Monday?
   Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="Day,Property,Violent
Mon,7.2,5.7
Tue,5,4.5
Wed,6.3,3.6
Thu,5.4,4
Fri,9.5,5.6
Sat,16,10.9
Sun,14.2,8.6", header=TRUE, sep=",")

#I would consider the weekdays ordered, so let's turn them into an ordered factor.
DF$Day <- ordered(as.character(DF$Day), as.character(DF$Day))

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
data.melt <- melt(DF,id.vars="Day")

ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=Day, y= value, fill= variable), 
               data= data.melt, position = position_dodge(width = .9))
```

[image]

This works just fine. You don't see much, because you only have one value per box. If you want to actually see the colours, you need more values per day and variable. Alternatively, you could use `geom_point`:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=Day, y= value, colour= variable), 
               data= data.melt, position = position_dodge(width = .9))
```

[image]